# How to validate cell's data using apache POI when modifying existing excel sheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have to fill some existing Excel tables with data. Some of the cells have data validation. Something like the value should be from list ["AA", "BB", "CC"]. 
I can set the value with `cell.setCellValue("WRONG")`, but the value is not validated and I couldn't find any examples of how to do it.
There are tons of examples how to create validations and evaluating formulas is easy, but I am truly stuck at this point.
So is it possible to do with Apache Poi or should I use something else?